# Apache Spark - shuffle writes more data than the size of the input data

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I use Spark 2.1 in local mode and I'm running this simple application.

```scala
val N = 10 << 20

sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", (N + 1).toString)
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", "false")

val df1 = sparkSession.range(N).selectExpr(s"id as k1")
val df2 = sparkSession.range(N / 5).selectExpr(s"id * 3 as k2")

df1.join(df2, col("k1") === col("k2")).count()
```

Here, the range(N) creates a dataset of *Long* (with unique values), so I assume that the size of

> - df1 = N * 8 bytes ~ 80MB
> - df2 = N / 5 * 8 bytes ~ 16MB

Ok now let's take df1 as an example.
**df1 consists of 8 partitions** and **shuffledRDDs of 5**, so I assume that

> - # of mappers (M) = 8
> - # of reducers (R) = 5

As the # of partitions is low, Spark will use the Hash Shuffle which will create **M * R files** in the disk but I haven't understood if every file has all the data, thus **each_file_size = data_size** resulting to **M * R * data_size** files or **all_files = data_size**.

However when executing this app, shuffle write of **df1 = 160MB** which doesn't match either of the above cases.

[Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUp1T.png)

What am I missing here? Why has the shuffle write data doubled in size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's see what `data size total(min, med, max)` means:

According to [SQLMetrics.scala#L88](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetrics.scala#L88-L90) and [ShuffleExchange.scala#L43](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/ShuffleExchange.scala#L43-L44), the `data size total(min, med, max)` we see is the final value of `dataSize` metric of shuffle. Then, how is it updated? It get updated each time a record is serialized: [UnsafeRowSerializer.scala#L66](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/UnsafeRowSerializer.scala#L66) by `dataSize.add(row.getSizeInBytes)` (`UnsafeRow` is the internal representation of records in Spark SQL).

Internally, `UnsafeRow` is backed by a `byte[]`, and is copied directly to the underlying output stream during serialization, its `getSizeInBytes()` method just return the length of the `byte[]`. Therefore, the initial question is transformed to: Why the bytes representation is twice big as the only `long` column a record have? This [UnsafeRow.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow.java#L49-L52) doc gives us the answer:

> Each tuple has three parts: [null bit set] [values] [variable length portion]
>
> The bit set is used for null tracking and is aligned to 8-byte word boundaries.  It stores one bit per field.

since it's 8-byte word aligned, the only 1 null bit is taking another 8 byte, the same width as the long column. Therefore, each `UnsafeRow` represents your one-long-column-row using 16 bytes.